# Spring data and multiple schema config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, multi-tenant

I'm trying to configure spring boot 1.3.5 + spring data with one datasource and multiples schemas. I've read a lot of post but none helped me.

I want that each costumer has it own schema and i want to create it at a runtime as soon as the new client costumer.

Can someone put an example to help me do it?

Comment: Three schemas in one database sounds like three data sources to me.  You'd have one annotated as primary and the others as secondary.

Comment: My problem is that i have to change the schema at a runtime. As soon as the costumer logs in, i need to identify the schema and change it.

Comment: If you have 1,000,000 users, does that mean a million schema changes?  That can never, ever scale.

Comment: I wont have this much.

Comment: Obviously.  The point stands: It can't scale.  You should have a schema that allows you to add users by inserting data, not changing a schema.  I would advise a redesign.